# Notation meaning when a matrix is equal to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

This may be a silly linear algebra question, but I'm reading something on calculating a homography matrix and there is a notation that I'm not so familiar with, a matrix equated with a vector. The equation starts with the assumption that a homography matrix is such:

$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
    h_{11}  & h_{12} & h_{13} \\
    h_{21}  & h_{22} & h_{23} \\
    h_{31}  & h_{32} & h_{32} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} h_1 \\ h_2 \\ h_3 \end{bmatrix}$

Does this notation mean that the $3\times1$ vector is an abbreviation of the $3 \times 3$ homography matrix?

Comment: Presumably, yes.  In particular, $h_1$ is the row vector $[h_{11}, h_{12}, h_{13}]$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks!